# Bubbles Background in AS3

Tags: animation, actionscript-3, background, gsap

I found 3 videos from SnorklTV.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUM0i0DLKk0
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_44H68-QciU
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9NUkmQDB1k

There is a problem: GreenSock still works to use it, but it is no longer officially supported.
Error 1172: Definition com.greensock could not be found.

Code:

```
var bubbleMax: Number = 50;
var tl: TimelineMax = new TimelineMax();

function createBubble() {
    var Bubble: Bubble = new Bubble();
    Bubble.y = 380;
    Bubble.x = randomRange(25, 610);
    Bubble.alpha = 1;
    addChild(Bubble);

    var nestedTL: TimelineMax = new TimelineMax();
    var speed: Number = randomRange(1, 3);
    var wiggle: Number = randomRange(25, 50);
    wiggle = Math.random() > .5 ? wiggle : -wiggle;

    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, speed, {
        y: -40,
        ease:Quad.easeIn
    }));
    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, .5, {
        scaleX: speed,
        scaleY: speed,
        alpha: randomRange(.5, 1)
    }));

    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, speed * .25, {
        x: String(wiggle),
        repeat: randomRange(1, 4),
        yoyo: true
    }));
    tl.append(nestedTL, speed * -.89);
}

function randomRange(min: Number, max: Number): Number {
    return min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function init() {
    for (var count: Number = 0; count < bubbleMax; count++) {
        createBubble();
    }
}
init();
```

Any ideas for the codes without importing Greensock?

Comment: What's wrong with importing Greensock? You can [download it here](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-AS3/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) and put the `com` folder in same place as your FLA. That should fix the error about : `Definition com.greensock could not be found.`

Comment: I just downloaded but where do I put them, in the local disk or an external disk?

Comment: Read my comment again... _"Put the `com` folder in same place as your FLA."_ ... This means put it in the **same folder** of where you saved the FLA (that has this shown code that you posted in your Question)

Comment: Now that I have the code, how would I make it on each frame?

Comment: You'll have to import it on each page (**Stage** frame) that needs it. The best way is to **keep all your code on frame 1**. If you need to show different pages/screens/frames whatever then use a MovieClip, where the MClip itself shows the different screens... Never move the Stage to another frame if making a game. Use `.addChild` and `.visible = true`... to put new things (MovieClip, Sprite) on screen.

Comment: Any ideas how to update my answer? And then I have an error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.

Comment: What do you think the error is telling you? Your code is doing something that is taking the computer a long time to finish. It could cause a crash, so it got auto-stopped. **How to fix** : You have a `For` loop that runs for `9999999999` times. Don't you think that number is **too big**? Is there enough space on screen to show 9,999,999,999 bubbles? **You fix by using a small number like 20 or 200**.

Comment: PS: Down-voted for having a `For` loop that runs **9.9 billion** times. Then asking why the computer gives error about a "long process time" from such code.

Comment: I understand the problem, but what about non-stop looping after the last number.

Comment: I don't even know what your _"After the last number"_ means. Please give **real useful information** when communicating. No one can see your screen so don't just read a "last number" on your screen and then think the whole world knows what magic number you are talking about... Say what you mean or else get very slow progress...

Comment: PS: If you're saying the error happens even if you use a small number like 1 for For-loop then something is broken. You'll have create the code `function createBubble()` in small parts until the error happens to know which thing to fix.

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

var bubbleMax: Number = 200;
var tl: TimelineMax = new TimelineMax();

function createBubble() {
    var Bubble: bubble = new bubble();
    Bubble.y = 430;
    Bubble.x = randomRange(25, 610);
    Bubble.alpha = 0;
    addChild(Bubble);
    Bubble.visible = true;

    var nestedTL: TimelineMax = new TimelineMax();
    var speed: Number = randomRange(1, 3);
    var wiggle: Number = randomRange(25, 50);
    wiggle = Math.random() > .5 ? wiggle : -wiggle;

    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, speed, {
        y: -40,
        ease:Quad.easeIn
    }));
    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, .5, {
        scaleX: speed,
        scaleY: speed,
        alpha: randomRange(.5, 1)
    }));

    nestedTL.insert(TweenMax.to(Bubble, speed * .25, {
        x: String(wiggle),
        repeat: randomRange(1, 4),
        yoyo: true
    }));
    tl.append(nestedTL, speed * -.89);
}

function randomRange(min: Number, max: Number): Number {
    return min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function init() {
    for (var count: Number = 0; count < bubbleMax; count++) {
        createBubble();
    }
}
init();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).